# Hide Buttons Back, Home, Android Applications

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I have problems to be able to implement correctly how to hide the buttons that are located at the bottom/footer. Those 3 buttons of Back, Home, Applications. I am implementing this code and it works correctly, it hides the TOP navigation bar and the Footer one. But the problem is when I click on my EditText, which appears the Virtual Keyboard. Once finished what you want to write, the 3 buttons of Back, Home, Applications. They are back visible. What do I need to implement? What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}
private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the view into listener in `onCreate`! Once I implemented this code. I am giving this sample to you:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    View decorView = hideSystemUI();
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new 
    View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    });
}

private View hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
         View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    return decorview;
}
```